# How to update a field using its previous value in MongoDB/Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I know I can do an update using `$set`:

```
Contact.update({
    _id: request.id
}, {
    $set: { name: newNameValue }
}, {
    upsert: false
}, function(err) { ... });
```

But in this case, instead of passing `newNameValue`, I'd like to use the previous `name` value to compute the new one. Let's say I want to capitalize the old name, something like:

```
Contact.update({
    _id: request.id
}, {
    $set: { name: $old.name.toUpperCase() }
}, {
    upsert: false
}, function(err) { ... });
```

Comment: It's most likely not possible to do it with one statement.

Answer (score 2):

I think this has already been answered here: [How to add new data to current string in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43770216/how-to-add-new-data-to-current-string-in-mongodb/43770850#43770850), so please, check that for a more detailed answer, but anyway, in short, you can't do that with a single query.

The way to do it using `Mongoose`, as shown in [this official Mongoose example](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html):

```
Contact.findById(request.id, (err, contract) => {
    if (err) return handleError(err);

    contract.name = contract.name.toUpperCase();

    contract.save((err, contractContract) => {
        if (err) return handleError(err);

        ...
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know it's not possible. You would need to find and then update

```
Contact
    .find({
        _id: request.id
    })
    .exec(function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                return ...;
            }
            Contact.findByIdAndUpdate(request.id, {
                $set: {
                    name: data.name.toUpperCase()
                }
            }, {
                new: true
            }, function(err, doc) {
                if (err) return ...;
                console.log(doc)
            });
        }
```